# Intermediate Value Theorem Proof

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $f(x)=\dfrac{20}{(x^6+x^4+x^2+1)}$.

I need to show that for any $k \in [5,20]$, there is a point $c \in [0,1]$ such that $f(c)=k$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know the intermediate value theorem?

Comment: Start by computing $f(0)$ and $f(1)$.

Comment: Yeah, in essence, if $f$ is cts on $[a,b]$ and and $k$ is a number between $f(a)$ and $f(b)$, then there is some point $c \in (a,b)$ s.t. $f(c)=k$

Comment: hmm so $f(0)= 20$ and $f(1)=5$

Comment: @PaulGerard  Now, put $a=0$, $b=1$ to what you have written.

Comment: Is it that easy to simply plug in my values for $a$ and $b$ and use the IVT to justify?

Comment: Yes, it is, provided that you can show $f(x)$ is continuous on $[0,1]$.

Comment: Can i similarly show that for any $k \in (0,5]$, there is a point $c \geq 1$ s.t. $f(c)=k$?

Comment: May be? If you can prove that there exists a point $d\ge1$ such that $f(d)<k$ and $f$ is continuout also in $[1,d]$.

Answer (score 1):

Observe that $x^6+x^4+x^2+1>0 \quad \forall x\in \mathbb{R}$ and is continuous(see [proving continuity of polynomials](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/732124/63095)). Now $f(x)$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ and observe that $f(1)=5, f(0)=20$. [Intermediate value theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem) tells that for every $k$ such that  $5\le k\le 20$ there exists a $c\in [0,1]$ such that $f(c)=k$.