# Let $x_n \rightarrow x$ and let $p(t)$ be a polynomial. Show that $p(x_n) \rightarrow p(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, polynomials

I want to solve the proof by using mathematical induction. I'm just not exactly sure of how I should start, like how should I do the base case?

Comment: This is asking to prove polynomials are continuous, so this link might be helpful: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/732115/how-can-i-prove-that-a-polynomial-with-degree-n-is-continuous-everywhere-in

Comment: The proof depends on what is given. Can we use the fact that if f and g are convergent sequences, then f*g is convergent?