# Formal proof function is continuous

Tags: calculus, continuity

I'm a bit stuck in this formal proof that the functions is continuos in all of it's domain.

$f(x)= 3(x^2+1)^3$

$ \epsilon >0 , \delta > 0  $

$|x-c|<\delta  \to  |3(x^2+1)^3-3(c^2+1)^3|     \to   3|x^6-c^6+3x^4+3x^2-3c^4-3c^2| $

that's where I get to by myself. Could somebody  help me out :) . Thanks

Comment: I think maybe look at the proof that if $f$ and $g$ are continuous, then so is $f \cdot g$.

Comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/732115/how-can-i-prove-that-a-polynomial-with-degree-n-is-continuous-everywhere-in) related question.

Comment: Or maybe use $a^3 - b^3 = (a - b)(a^2 + ab + b^2)$.

Comment: Thank you guys for your insight. Totally forgot about the  property mentioned by @TrevorGunn . I think i'll go that way.

Answer (score 2):

As I said in the comments: $a^3 - b^3 = (a - b)(a^2 + ab + b^2)$ so we can write this as

\begin{align}
&3|(x^2 + 1) - (y^2 + 1)| \cdot |(x^2 + 1)^2 + (x^2 + 1)(y^2 + 1) + (y^2 + 1)^2| \\
={} & 3|x - y| \cdot |x + y| \cdot |(x^2 + 1)^2 + (x^2 + 1)(y^2 + 1) + (y^2 + 1)^2|.
\end{align}

Then you just need a crude bound on $3|x + y| \cdot |(x^2 + 1)^2 + (x^2 + 1)(y^2 + 1) + (y^2 + 1)^2|$.